# Send module version as command line argument to SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using TeamCity to run a bash script that is utilizing SBT Native Packager to publish an image to Docker. The sbt portion of the bash script looks something like this:

```
sbt -DdockerRepository=$repo -DpackageName=$packageName -D myproject/docker:publish
```

I want to pass on the TeamCity build number as a version number to my package. Today I specify the version number manually in settings in build.sbt:

```
settings(
  version := "0.20",
  ....,
  dockerBaseImage := "example.com:5000/linux/java8:latest",
  dockerRepository in Docker := Some("example.com/myoldrepo"),
  dockerUpdateLatest := true'
)
```

I want to be able to do it like this:

```
activator -Dversion=0.21 -DpackageName=myproject -D myproject/docker:publish
```

but this does not seem to work. Yet overriding the dockerRepository like I do above is working.

How can I pass my desired version number into SBT from the command line/TeamCity?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could set version before publish:

```
sbt 'set version := "1.0"' docker:publish
```

Comment: Thanks. What is considered more correct of this approach and Andrzejs answer above?

Comment: The main difference is that my approach isn't require to change you build. Both of them are correct IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```scala
val myVersion = util.Properties.propOrNone("version").getOrElse("0.20")

val myDockerBaseImage = util.Properties.propOrNone("dockerBaseImage").
                    getOrElse("example.com:5000/linux/java8:latest")

lazy val myProject = Project("myProject",file("path")).settings(
  version := myVersion,
  dockerBaseImage := myDockerBaseImage,
  ....,
  dockerRepository in Docker := Some("example.com/myoldrepo"),
  dockerUpdateLatest := true
)
```

And then call it (depends on your sbt installation):

`SBT_OPTS="-Dversion=0.21" sbt`

`sbt -Dversion=0.21`

`activator -Dversion=0.21`