# switch from maven to sbt

Tags: spring, scala, maven, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to replace simple Maven project to SBT project. But I have 
faced few problems. In maven I have several profiles for project like

```
 <profile>
                <id>name</id>
                <properties>
                    <tomcatHome>/apache-tomcat-7.0.42</tomcatHome>
                    <config.folder>/conf/</config.folder>
                    <data.folder>/conf/data</data.folder>
                </properties>
            </profile>
```

this profiles can be changed for different builds in maven

```
mvn package -P name
```

or can be used by Intellij Idea for embedded maven build and server launching

Also properties can be used in spring config (through placeholders).

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${config.folder} />
```

How can i write similar configuration for sbt? 
I did not find anything similar in the documentation
Thanks

Comment: See [Send module version as command line argument to SBT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36331828/651140).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sbt file you can use scala syntax.

Simple example.

```scala
val akkaVersion = util.Properties.propOrNone("akka.version").getOrElse("2.4.3")

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion
```

When you call `sbt` the version will be set to default "2.4.3". But when you call:

`sbt -Dakka.version=2.3.13` you version 2.3.13 will be used.

Next example with [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/2.1.md). You can choose either JettyPlugin or TomcatPlugin.

```scala
val containerPlugin = util.Properties.propOrNone("use.tomcat").
                    map(_ => TomcatPlugin).getOrElse(JettyPlugin)

enablePlugins(containerPlugin)
```

When you call:
`sbt -Duse.tomcat` TomcatPlugin will be used. Otherwise JettyPlugin.

Comment: main question is: how can I pass arguments from **.sbt** file (like `<data.folder>/conf/data</data.folder>` from **.pom** file) to **spring** context (`<context:property-placeholder location="file:${config.folder} />`)?